# How to modify a regular expression to parse a parameter from a YouTube URL

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, url, youtube

I've got this regular expression:

```
/^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
```

It will parse the video id from a YouTube URL such as

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ciG_6Y3rD0&feature=youtu.be&t=6m40s

or

> http://youtu.be/6ciG_6Y3rD0?t=6m40s

I want to modify it so that it also parses the **t** parameter.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Howie

Comment: Can the `t` parameter show up in any order in the querystring?

Comment: What language are you using this in? JavaScript, PHP, etc?

Comment: JavaScript. and t can be anywhere in the URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture YouTube video ID (and time seek parameter `t` if exists)

RegExp:

```
^(?:https?\:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v\=))([\w-]{10,12})(?:[\&\?\#].*?)*?(?:[\&\?\#]t=([\dhm]+s))?$
```

Demo here: http://fiddle.re/w1nn6

PS: you'll note I improved your original RegEx to validate the YouTube link safely